# move uploaded file to root/public_html

Tags: laravel, upload

i have a laravel project and its uploaded on a sharing host
i have this code for moving uploaded file to folder : 
$request->file->move(public_path('images\banners'), $new_name);

my website is like : 
root/
    laravel
    public_html

i just want to move uploaded file to public_html folder

```
public function register()
{
    //
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return realpath(base_path().'/../public_html');
    });
}
```

i try this but its not working

Answer (score 0):

The laravel way is to use FlySystem. Open up `config/filesystems.php` and add a new entry for `public_html`.

```php
'disks' => [

    'public_html' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   =>  '/full/path/to/public_html', 
    ],
...
```

Then use it as `Storage::disk('public_html')->put('filename', 'contents');`. There are other methods on the docs on how to move or upload files to a specific storage here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem.

Additionally, instead of specifying the fullpath you can use helper functions such as `storage_path()` or `public_path()` depending on where your directory is.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $file = $request->file('image');
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
    $filename =time().'.'.$extension;
    $path = $file->move(public_path('uploads'), $filename);
    $newPath = explode('\public\\', $path);
    $filePath = end($newPath);
```